# Pull latest record from data using distinct on?

Tags: psycopg2

I have a data that looks like below:

```
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15

    2020-10-30 17:57:17,False,2020-07-01,14,2,False,0.0,True,30.0,True,30.0,True,True,True,False
    2020-10-30 17:57:17,False,2020-07-01,15,2,True,28.0,False,0.0,False,0.0,True,True,True,False
    2020-11-15 17:57:17,True,2020-07-01,5,2,True,28.0,False,0.0,False,0.0,True,True,True,False
    2020-11-15 17:57:17,False,2020-07-01,7,2,False,0.0,True,30.0,True,30.0,True,True,True,False
```

My query looks like the following:

```
  select distinct on (col3) col4
    from table where col13 is true and col15 is false
    and col3 = '2020-07-01'
    and col1 <= '2020-09-16'
    and col2 is false order by col3, col1 asc;
```

My expected answer should be [14, 15] since these are earliest records for '2020-07-01'. However using the above query I only get [15]. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using the following query:

```
    select distinct col4,
    from table where col13 is true and col15 is false
    and col3 = '2020-07-01'
    and col1 = (select min(col1) from table
    where col1 <= '2020-09-16' and col3 = '2020-07-01')
    and col2 is false;
```